# Do archtop guitars need special strings different from flat top guitars?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, strings

It has dawned on me that I might possibly improve the acoustic sound of my Epiphone Emperor archtop if I used different strings. It has a floating humbucker and sounds really nice when I  play it electric but I like to practice unplugged and the sound is a little shoe boxy when played that way. Anyone have any thoughts or experience to share?

Comment: Never played a shoebox, but heavier gauge strings, flatwound or tapewound will give a little more mellowness. Obviously be aware of too much change in tension overall.

Comment: @Tim- I have 12 gauge strings on it now and it plays real nice, I'm just interested in getting as much out of my instrument as I can sound wise but I realize there may be limits to what I can achieve. I'm just trying to get it up to those limits. I'll give some flat-wound strings a try.

Comment: FWIW, if I had that guitar I'd put Thomastik George Benson 11s or 12s on it. They're flatwounds. They have solid nickel wrapping so they won't go suddenly dull after a week like nickel-plated wraps like any other flats.